# Python Tkinter How To Use Button For Consol Entry (Input())?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to set the button spade2's text to the user's input in the main loop but it doesn't seem to work. Any Ideas? Thanks. I am quite new to Tkinter.

```py
class GUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry("500x500")
        
    def Clicked(self,btn):
        text = btn.cget("text")
        print("{}".format(text))

    def buttons(self):
        spade2 = Button(self.root, text = "This Text", padx = 50)
        spade2.configure(command=lambda btn=spade2: self.Clicked(btn))
        spade2.grid()

# # # # # # Main Loop # # # # # # 
gui = GUI()
gui.buttons()

# Counter Start
counter = CountingLog(8)
counter.Merg()

# Main Program Loop
while True:
    _input = input()
    if _input == "q":
        break
    inputSep = _input.split(" ")
    card = Card(inputSep[0], inputSep[1])
    # Excutes Other Code
```

When I try to set the text of the button to the user input it gives me this:

```
card = Card(inputSep[0], inputSep[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

But when I manually type the input everything works.

Comment: why to use `input()` if you want to create GUI - it looks stupid. You don't have to write URL in text console to change page in web browser. Use `tk.Entry()` or messagebox with `Entry` to get value in GUI.

Comment: if you error shows you which line makes problem then first you could use `print()`, `print(len(...))`, `print(type(...))` to check what you really have in variables.

Comment: `tkinter` (similar to other GUIs) has to run `root.mainloop()` to work correctly - it runs loop which gets key/mouse events from system, sends events to widgets, updates values in widgets and finally (re)draw window and widgets.

Comment: If user put single word then `split()` will give list with single element but you need two elements to get `[1]` - and you should check `len(inputSep) >= 2` before you can use `[1]` and sometimes `[0]`